# Database design for 3 strong entity sets

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to design a database for 3 tables: Teacher, Course, Student.
  - A teacher can have many students and can teach many courses.
  - A student can have many teachers and study many courses.
  - A course can be taught by many teachers and can have many students enrolled.
I want to be able to determine that which student is studying which course, and is taught by which teacher.

Comment: You might want to use switching tables, that only has foreign keys to the entity tables...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yeah...i thought abt that too...but wont that mean the table will be too big, thus may result in low query performance.

Comment: [_Tips on many:many mapping tables_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE teacher (
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE course(
  id   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  -- other columns, constraints, etc...
);
CREATE TABLE student_course (
  student_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES student(id),
  course_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES course(id),
);
CREATE TABLE teacher_course (
  teacher_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES teacher(id),
  course_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES course(id),
);

SELECT s.id, s.name, c.id, c.name, .id, t.name
FROM student s
  JOIN student_course sc ON s.id = sc.student_id
  JOIN course c ON sc.course_id = c.id
  JOIN teacher_course tc ON c.id = tc.course.id
  JOIN teacher t ON tc.teacher_id = t.id
```

Comment: Where are the indexes!!

Comment: @RickJames What indexes?

Comment: Tables are mostly useless without indexes, at least when you get beyond a few rows.

Comment: PK's and FK's create implicit indexes, but I do not know what other columns are there...